# asio::io_service::run doesnt return after boost::asio::io_service::work is destroyed

Tags: c++, boost, asio

As title says I'm having this problem when I can't understand why this thread

[image]

never stops running even after `Client`'s destructor destroys `asio::io_service::work` variable

[image]

When I'm running this program output is always like this

[image]

Anyone sees what I'm missing here?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

using namespace boost;


class Client{
public:

    Client(const Client& other) = delete;

    Client()
    {
        m_work.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_ios));

        m_thread.reset(new std::thread([this]()
        {
            m_ios.run();
        }));
    }

    ~Client(){ close(); }

private:

    void close();

    asio::io_service m_ios;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;

};

void Client::close()
{
    m_work.reset(nullptr);

    if(m_thread->joinable())
    {
        std::cout << "before joining thread" << std::endl;
        m_thread->join();
        std::cout << "after joining thread" << std::endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    {
         Client client;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

---

After **StPiere** comments I changed code to this and it worked :)

```
class Client{
public:

    Client(const Client& other) = delete;

    Client()
    {
        m_work.reset(new boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>(boost::asio::make_work_guard(m_ios)));
        m_thread.reset(new std::thread([this]()
        {
            m_ios.run();
        }));
    }

    ~Client(){ close(); }

private:

    void close();

    asio::io_context m_ios;

    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>> m_work;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;

};
```

Comment: which compiler/os/boost version ? on vc2019 , boost 1.75 it works fine.

Comment: @StPiere I'm using TDM-GCC 9.2.0 compiler and 1.75 boost version. Also using it in CodeBlocks if it makes any difference

Comment: io_service is basically deprecated and should be replaced with io_context. Can you try and check if you get the same issue by using io_context instead of io_service ?

Comment: Ohh thanks man. I didnt know it was changed. I'm using 1 cookbook to make this example so I'll change it and will let u know

Comment: and if it still doesnt work, you can try replacing io_context::work with io_context::executor_work_guard, because io_context::work is also deprecated. see boost docs.

Comment: @StPiere Thanks. Changing jsut io_service to context didnt help. But it will take some time for me to test that work_guard coz I have no idea how to use it right now

Comment: @StPiere Bro I just found example with work guard and it worked. :) Thank you so much bro. You should write it as answer

Comment: glad that could help.

Comment: No doubt you have other async operations pending on the service. No need to use unique_ptr with either the thread nor the executor_work_guard (the latter has a `.reset()` member of its own). Sometimes when heisenbugs like this appear there is a hidden cause (like you're not debugging an up-to-date build for some reason)

Comment: @sehe Ohh im new to this `executor_work_guard `. I will keep this in mind and update my code. I have to research a bit what has changed in boost::asio. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error on either compiler.
Here [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bkIffx1exU8pHx8I) for gcc 9.3 and boost 1.73

Normally the work destructor will use something like `InterLockedDecrement` on windows to decrement the number of outstanding works.

It looks like some compiler or io_service/work implementation issue.

As stated in comments, `io_service` and `io_service::work` are **deprecated** in terms of `io_context` and `executor_work_guard`.